# Python ElementTree XML: adding external link

Tags: python, xml

I'm totally new to XML in general and the XML python package. 
I'm trying to add a hyperlink to an XML tree but it's not quite working.

I'm using Python's ElementTree:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
```

This is the code snippet for the element I'm trying to add to the XML tree:

```
para = ET.SubElement(..., "p", link_id=1)
ET.SubElement(para, "link", id=2, type="external", url="http://www.google.com").text="Google.com"
```

I'm not sure how I should be adding the text to the link. It's producing this:

```
<p link_id="1">
  <link id="2" type="external" url="http://www.google.com"/>
</p>
```

When I think I want it to look like this:

```
<p link_id="1">
  <link id="2" type="external" url="http://www.google.com">Google.com</link>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the attributes in quotes. This will make your code look like this:

```
para = ET.SubElement(xml, "p", link_id="1")
ET.SubElement(para, "link", id="2", type="external", url="http://www.google.com").text="Google.com"
```

Then the output should be as expected:

```
<p link_id="1">
  <link id="2" type="external" url="http://www.google.com">Google.com</link>
</p>
```

**Note:**
You also had a superfluous `>` in your expression.

Comment: Thanks! Yes that ```>``` was a typo. Will edit and remove.